# cgminer hardware errors with sapphire r9 270x oc?

Tags: graphics

I am mining litecoin with a Sapphire r9 270x 2GB card but i am unable to go anywhere above intensity 13 without a lot of hardware errors. At intensity 13 it is hashing stable at about 335kh/s with 0 hardware errors... however, if i turn it up to 14 i get 90 hardware errors after 1 minute...  i have tried countless  thread concurrency combinations/settings with no success... However, if i ignore hardware errors i am able to get about 430kh/s, but with many hardware errors.

Answer (score 1):

you need to increase the intensity to 19 and use the following parameters

--scrypt -I 19 -w 256 --thread-concurrency 15808 --shaders 1280 -w 256 --lookup-gap 0 --no-submit-stale -g 1 --gpu-engine 1070 --gpu-memclock 1500 --temp-target 75 --auto-fan

for --thread-concurrency you can use any number between 14080 to 16192, test starting with 14080 just add 192 each time until you reach 16192.

minimum 3GB of RAM memory in the system.

This gives about 440-450 khs.